# Scrape facebook AttributeError

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am beginner for Python,

How I can solve

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'Request'
```

As I view other post, still can't understand how solve the problem

Here the screen capture of the error

[image]

And this is the code (I refer from https://github.com/minimaxir/facebook-page-post-scraper/blob/master/get_fb_posts_fb_page.py)

```
import urllib.request
import json, datetime, csv, time

app_id = "xxx"
app_secret = "xxx" # DO NOT SHARE WITH ANYONE!

access_token = "xxx"

page_id = 'xxx'


def testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token):

    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + page_id +'/feed'
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters

    # retrieve data
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)    
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

    print (data)

def request_until_succeed(url):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)  
    success = False
    while success is False:
        try: 
            response = urllib.urlopen(req)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            time.sleep(5)

            print (url, datetime.datetime.now())

    return response.read()


def getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, num_statuses):

    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com"
    node = "/" + page_id + "/feed" 
    parameters = "/?fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true),shares&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (num_statuses, access_token) # changed
    url = base + node + parameters

    # retrieve data
    data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))

    return data


def processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status):

    # The status is now a Python dictionary, so for top-level items,
    # we can simply call the key.

    # Additionally, some items may not always exist,
    # so must check for existence first

    status_id = status['id']
    status_message = '' if 'message' not in status.keys() else status['message'].encode('utf-8')
    link_name = '' if 'name' not in status.keys() else status['name'].encode('utf-8')
    status_type = status['type']
    status_link = '' if 'link' not in status.keys() else status['link']


    # Time needs special care since a) it's in UTC and
    # b) it's not easy to use in statistical programs.

    status_published = datetime.datetime.strptime(status['created_time'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
    status_published = status_published + datetime.timedelta(hours=-5) # EST
    status_published = status_published.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # best time format for spreadsheet programs

    # Nested items require chaining dictionary keys.

    num_likes = 0 if 'likes' not in status.keys() else status['likes']['summary']['total_count']
    num_comments = 0 if 'comments' not in status.keys() else status['comments']['summary']['total_count']
    num_shares = 0 if 'shares' not in status.keys() else status['shares']['count']

    # return a tuple of all processed data
    return (status_id, status_message, link_name, status_type, status_link,
           status_published, num_likes, num_comments, num_shares)

def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
    with open('%s_facebook_statuses.csv' % page_id, 'w') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file)
        w.writerow(["status_id", "status_message", "link_name", "status_type", "status_link",
           "status_published", "num_likes", "num_comments", "num_shares"])

        has_next_page = True
        num_processed = 0   # keep a count on how many we've processed
        scrape_starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

        print (page_id, scrape_starttime)

        statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, 100)

        while has_next_page:
            for status in statuses['data']:
                w.writerow(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status))

                # output progress occasionally to make sure code is not stalling
                num_processed += 1
                if num_processed % 1000 == 0:
                    print (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now())

            # if there is no next page, we're done.
            if 'paging' in statuses.keys():
                statuses = json.loads(request_until_succeed(statuses['paging']['next']))
            else:
                has_next_page = False


        print (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
```

Comment: all code need 4 space indentation to be colored on SO

Comment: always add error message as a text, not screen capture. There is no `am` in english - there is `I am`.

Comment: I don't see `req = urllib.Request(url)` in your code - maybe you use wrong file with wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `urllib.Request()` in Python 3 - there is `urllib.request.Request()`.

---

**EDIT:** you have `url = urllib.Request(url)` in error message but I don't see this line in your code - maybe you run wrong file.

Comment: thank you for your help. I solve the problem already. I add on the line url = urllib.Request(url) into code. thanks